# Past perfect usage with simultaneous events?

Tags: past-perfect

I was reading *To Kill a Mockingbird* and I came across a sentence:

> This was the first {time} he had let us know he knew a lot more about something than we thought he knew.

I can't understand the usage of past perfect in the second clause (he had let us know). Past perfect is used when one action occurs before another in the past. This much I know, but in this case the occurrences are pretty much simultaneous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the past tense versions...

> 1: ***That was*** the first time I **had done** it
>    2: ***That was*** the first time I **did** it

...with the corresponding *present tense* versions...

> 3: ***This is*** the first time I **have done** it
>    4: ***This is*** the first time I **do** it

Although #1 is probably the more common (perhaps even "more *correct*") version of the first pair, most native speakers wouldn't particularly notice anything unusual about #2. But native speakers would *never* use #4 - which is a *very* common error among speakers of certain other languages, so even if the speaker had a perfect English accent, the assumption would be "non-native speaker".

---

I think the reason we require Present Perfect (essentially, a ***Past*** form) in the *second* pair is because *semantically* there's an implicit reference to the past (all the time *before* "now, time of speaking", during which I *hadn't* done it). But because we're already in the past with the first pair, it seems unnecessary (but not actually "incorrect") to specifically distinguish between "past" and "even earlier past".

Bear in mind that *as a general principle*, native speakers will normally tend to avoid the additional complexity of Past Perfect if they don't feel they obviously *need* it.

Answer (score 2):

"This was the first time he **let** us know..." could suggest that there were other subsequent times when that happened: a second time, a third time, etc.

The past perfect in "This was the first time he **had let** us know..." does not reflect past before past but is the past form of a life experience: up to then, he had never let them know. It's easier in the present:

- He has never let us know the truth before. This **is** the first time he **has**.

If backshifted, "has" becomes "had":

- That **was** the first time he **had** let us know the truth.